# handlebars_assets pushes the javascript source to the html element

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, handlebars.js, asset-pipeline

I don't know why this is happening, perhaps there are some HTML experts out there that can explain what is going on...

the javascript

```
        var template1 = HandlebarsTemplates['search-card'];
        $("#print-search-card").html(template1(tiles));
```

The html (haml)

```
.col-sm-12
  .row#whole
    .hidden-xs.hidden-sm.col-md-2#sidebar
      #print-sidebar-search
    .col-sm-10#content
      .grid
        #print-search-card
```

the template

```
{{#each siftLocal}}
<div class="col">
  <div class="search-card"><img class="lazyImg card-loading" data-original="{{image}}" alt="discover" width="250" height="250"></div>
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="text">
    <h3 class="text-left">Title</h3>
    <p class="text-left">Forage paleo darted iphone rainbow goth meggins, walking pop doom levitate beacon...</p>
    <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{comments}}
        </li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{likes}}</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="card-info">
    <img src="/sift/img/headshot.jpg" alt="headshot">
    <h4>{{name}}</h4>
</div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

The tiles variable`

```
var tiles = {
"siftLocal": [{
    "name": "Bush Allen",
    "job": "<ReferenceError: job is not defined>",
    "categories": "Baking",
    "email": "bushallen@cuizine.com",
    "phone": "+1 (993) 548-2009",
    "address": "Denver, Co",
    "comments": 40,
    "likes": 20,
    "followers": 40,
    "image": "/sift/img/discover.png",
    "profilePicture": "/sift/img/tyler1.png",
    "productPictures": [{
        "img1": "/sift/img/mac1.jpg",
        "img2": "/sift/img/mac2.jpg",
        "img3": "/sift/img/mac3.jpg"
    }]

}]
```

the result

[image]

Added tiles JSON and template source for clarity.

Comment: You're saying that `template1(tiles)` JavaScript function call is dumping the `template1` Handlebars template function into the page?

Comment: I think so, if you see the screenshot is starts with (function()...

Comment: It's like it is treating the javascript source as plain text and not recognizing it should be executed.

Comment: Are you precompiling the templates? If so, show how are you doing it please.

Comment: Show the `search-card` template, and the `tiles` context please.

Comment: I am not precompiling the templates, I am using the handlebars_assets gem which is what is compiling the template.